reactJS + Vite with firebase hosting - failed to load resources, blank web page, not working
Problem: Website only shows blank page with this console error message:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404()

GET https://ybmslaw.web.app/assets/index-1_Sn4P3O.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)    
GET https://ybmslaw.web.app/assets/index-DBxq5wpG.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)


I checked the source and it's only an (index) in there without the assets folder

MY FILES AND FILE STRUCTURE
below is my file structure, im not sure if there's anything wrong with it, but I have another website with this exact file structure yet that one works. The other website uses the similar configuration but for some reason that one works but this one doesn't.

firebase.json
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "../ybms",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "predeploy": [
      "npm run build"
    ]
  }
}

vite.config.json
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    outDir: "dist" // tells vite to output the build to a folder called dist
  },
  base: '/'
})

What I tried and ended up not solved:

Changed public: 'dist' to '../ybms' or '/dist' or './dist', etc basically all combinations
changed all files to have '/' or './' or no '/'
made it single html (didnt work made it worse with the mime type error)
removed base in vite.config.json
removed build in vite.config.json
fixed all my errors and removed all deprecated dependencies
waited atleast 15 minutes for firebase to load
cleared cache and hard restarted

Please save me, i'm not sure why firebase is being like this. It's 1:46 am, I've spent 3 days straight on this.

I updated my firebase-tools to 13.11.4 the latest, it was apparently on 10.8, I thought I updated my firebase-tools.
So I ran npm uninstall firebase-tools then npm install firebase-tools@latest
